# What's the proper way of connecting a signal to a JavaScript method?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, qml, javascript

In an Ubuntu phone application, I need to perform some logic when an event occurs.
Since I don't want to pollute the QML with too many lines of JavaScript, I made a class in an external file and I connected the signal to one of its methods:

**Main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 1.1
import "action.js" as ActionJs

MainView {
    objectName: "mainView"

    applicationName: "example.cos64"

    useDeprecatedToolbar: false

    width: units.gu(20)
    height: units.gu(20)

    Page {

        Button {
            id: clickMeButton

            text: "Click me"

            onClicked: {
                console.log('clicked');
            }

            Component.onCompleted: {
                var action = new ActionJs.Action();
                clickMeButton.clicked.connect(action.handleClick)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**action.js**

```
function Action() {

    this.handleClick = function() {
        console.log('handleClick');
        this.process();
    }

    this.process = function() {
        console.log('processing...')
    }
}
```

It works, but I can't call any other method from the slot:

```
Starting /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmlscene...
qml: clicked
qml: handleClick
file:///home/co64/projects/ubuntu/Example/action.js:5: TypeError: Property 'process' of object [object Object] is not a function
```

Why is 'process' not recognized as a function?
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: what happens if you `console.log(this.process)`?

Comment: it might be because `clickMeButton.clicked.connect` changes the context, i.e. changes `this`

Comment: `console.log(this.process)` shows `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the immediate problem is that the context changes inside the function definitions inside `Action`.  The `this` object inside `Action.handleClick()` is `Action.handleClick`, not `Action`.

But let's back up a little bit: why are you using the function-inside-a-function paradigm here?  This is common in browser Javascript, since there is no namespacing in that environment.  To avoid trampling other functions, you fake a namespace by creating an object to hold all of your functions.

However, QML *does* do namespacing.  Note that you had to reference `Action` as `ActionJS.Action` from the QML file.  Therefore, there's no need implement another namespace for your functions; just put them in the top level of the JS file:

```
function handleClick() {
    console.log("handleClick");
    process();
}

function process() {
    console.log("processing...");
}
```

Then in your QML file, do

```
Component.onCompleted: {
    clickMeButton.clicked.connect(ActionJS.handleClick)
}
```

Or, just

```
onClicked: ActionJS.handleClick()
```

I'm assuming here that you don't actually need an `Action` object for anything other than namespacing.  If you do, you should learn about [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype).  You may also want to know about [`.pragma library`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-resources.html#shared-javascript-resources-libraries), if you intend to use this JS file in multiple QML files.